# XPATH for sibling node based on condition of previous child

Tags: xml, xpath

I have following xml and would like to fetch the "cc" value of "type" ID where a "type" of student exist. I want XPATH to get the value 345.

I have tried this but not getting any value.//a/cc[type="bond"]/following-sibling::cc[type="id"]/value/text()

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root> 
  <a> 
    <bb>abc</bb>  
    <cc> 
      <type>id</type>  
      <value>345</value> 
    </cc>  
    <cc> 
      <type>student</type>  
      <value>567</value> 
    </cc>  
    <dd>ddd</dd> 
  </a>  
  <a> 
    <bb>zz</bb>  
    <cc> 
      <type>id</type>  
      <value>999</value> 
    </cc>  
    <cc> 
      <type>employee</type>  
      <value>890</value> 
    </cc>  
    <dd>2</dd> 
  </a> 
</root>
```

Comment: Why `type="bond"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `following-sibling` by `preceding-sibling` (and `bond` by `student`).

```
//a/cc[type="student"]/preceding-sibling::cc[type="id"]/value/text()
```

(Tested in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//a[cc[type="student"]]/cc[type="id"]/value/text()
```

(Tested in https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester)